# Javascript uniform postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, coding-style, updatepanel, uniform

Good afternoon all

Here is my scenario:

I have user controls within a master page and within a user control, I may have an update panel. I have the following bit of code I place within a usercontrol  that maintains various control styling during partial postback i.e. those controls affected within by an asp update panel.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            $("select, span, input").uniform();
```

Indeed, when an update panel does its thing, the Fancy Dan styling is maintained.

However, I have one gripe - when a 'large' partial postback occurs, occassionally you'll see the default, generic control styling reappear breifly and then the uniform kicks in to reapply the new fancy styles.

Is there any way I can avoid seeing the nasty old, default, bland stylings?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out working with PageManagerRequests: [MSDN Working With PageRequestManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398976%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

1. [Sys.WebForms.PageLoadingEventArgs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310960%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
2. [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager pageLoading Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383832%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

   ```
   $(function() {
       Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(beautify);
   });


   function beautify(sender, eventArgs) {
       // If we have event args
       if (eventArgs != null) {
           // for each panel that is being updated, update the html by adding color red
           // to select, span, input elements
           // must remember to call .html() to put html back into the panelsUpdating[i], otherwise it puts in the jQuery Object
           for (var i = 0; i < eventArgs.get_panelsUpdating().length; i++) {
               //My test code
               //var content = eventArgs._panelsUpdating[i].outerHTML;
               //var jContent = $(content);
               //$("input", jContent).css("color", "red");
               //jContent = $('<div>').append(jContent)
               //var jContentToContent = jContent.html();
               //alert(jContentToContent);
               //eventArgs._panelsUpdating[i].outerHTML = jContentToContent;


           //Cleaned up
           var jContent = $(eventArgs._panelsUpdating[i].outerHTML);
           $("select, span, input", jContent).uniform();
           jContent = $('&lt;div&gt;').append(jContent);
           eventArgs._panelsUpdating[i].outerHTML = jContent.html();
       }
   }


   }
   ```

**Edit:** I think you understood that the issue was the elements were being placed into the DOM (and therefore painted) before your javascript had a chance to make them uniform(). This intercepts the UpdatePanel and uniform()'s the code prior to it inserted into the DOM

**Edit 2** Alright, I've updated it a bunch, I tested this with my test code there and then included the code you're likely to add. Also, I took a short cut in eventArgs._panelsUpdating - i should really be using the get and set functions, but this works.

Comment: Sorry for being thick Prescott, but the onLoad bit - should this be applied to each of the controls onLoad event that is affected? Thanks for taking the time to look at this for me.

Comment: you're using jQuery, so $(function() { Sys... ; }); will work - you can put this anywhere in your <script> tags and it will fire when the document has loaded.

Comment: you might also have $(document).ready(function() { ... }); - same thing

Comment: Thicky Rich here again - encountering a nasty Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method error on the var updatedCode = eventArgs.get_dataItems() line. Nasty.

Comment: interesting - I don't have a set up at the moment to test - can you use firebug or something similar to put a breakpoint at the if(eventArgs != null) line, and inspect the eventArgs element?

Comment: Hello Prescott - basically, the eventArgs.get_dataItems() is coming back as undefined. I'm not sure where to go/what to do now!

Comment: All bad news - I misunderstood the get_dataItems() - you can register other data via server side code to update. That's all well and good, but not an easy solution to your problem. I set up a simple test on my end, I can get the beautify to call, and can inspect the object -but I can't figure out how to produce the "raw html" output - or something similar to be able to manipulate that

Comment: Also, it should be function beautify(sender, args), not beautify(args)

Comment: No need to apologise Prescott! I really appreciate the help.  I'll have a play with that now and let you know.